# why does dplyr::case_when always evaluate rhs in this example?

Tags: r, dplyr

Why does this code return ".txt" three times instead of once? Pls help.

```
dfs_repaired <- list(`x.txt` = data.frame())
  export <- purrr::pmap(list(
    data = dfs_repaired,
    path = names(dfs_repaired),
    type = stringr::str_extract(names(dfs_repaired), "\\..*")
  ),
  function(data, path, type) {
    dplyr::case_when(
      type == ".csv" ~ print(type),
      type == ".xlsx" ~ print(type),
      type == ".txt" ~ print(type)
    )
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dfs_repaired <- list(`x.txt` = data.frame())
export <- purrr::pmap(list(
  data = dfs_repaired,
  path = names(dfs_repaired),
  type = stringr::str_extract(names(dfs_repaired), "\\..*")
),
function(data, path, type) {
  if (type == ".csv") {
    print(type)
  } else if (type == ".xlsx") {
    print(type)
  } else if (type == ".txt") {
    print(type)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer the syntax of `case_when` if possible.

Answer (score 2):

The code only **returns** one ".txt" (look at the the value of `export`), although it prints it to the console three times.

You would not normally use an operation like `print()` on the RHS of a `case_when`.

The code for `case_when` includes the line `values <- args$rhs` which is then passed to another function. Just doing this assignment, when `args$rhs` (the terms on the right of the `~`) is a list of three `print(type)` statements, will execute that statement three times, and print `type` to the console.

However, the end result (the value of `export`) is correct.

Comment: Thanks. In the original code, I want to save `data` with the appropriate function depending on `type`, .e.g `type == ".txt" ~ readr::write_delim(data, path)`. However, it tries to save `data` with `readr::write_csv(data, path)`, even if LHS is `FALSE`. Any idea how to solve this whith `case_when`?

Comment: I see - there probably is a clever way of doing that, but I would be inclined to just split the dataset by type and have a separate section for each one to save the files using the appropriate function - I guess there are only a handful of different filetypes.